# Domain points to wrong directory in XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I just set up my XAMPP server after reinstalling Windows due to a hard drive failure. When I backed up my server files, I just copied EVERYTHING, all files and folders, from the htdocs folder. After I installed XAMPP and got the security stuff worked out, I went to copy the backed up htdocs files back to the new htdocs folder. Now, whenever I type in my domain name, the one that should point to the htdocs folder, because that is the default DocumentRoot, it instead gives me an error page saying "Access Forbidden", and the URL I see in my URL bar is "soandso.com/xampp", rather than just "soandso.com"

Why is it sending me to the htdocs/xampp folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of a wrong configuration. Check out

```
XAMPP-FOLDER/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and make sure you sure you have

```
<VirtualHost yourdomain.com>
ServerAdmin admin@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot "XAMPP-FOLDER/htdocs/domain-root-folder"
ServerName yourdomain.com
ServerAlias yourdomain.com
<Directory "XAMPP-FOLDER/htdocs/domain-root-folder">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

written there.